# Uploading Multiple files and save it on folder

Tags: asp.net

I have one web page in asp.net. In that I have put file upload button. When I click on that button, it opens the browser. I want that it should allow me to select Multiple files. When I select multiple files, I should be able to save them to some location. 
Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is example of multiple file upload

**http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/12/aspnet-upload-multiple-files-using.html**